# How can I edit multiple sprites in Sprite Editor at once?

Tags: unity, sprites

I have 100 sprites in one atlas. I want to edit some of them with same values.

For example, I want to edit sprite's position no 1 ~ 30. Do I have to edit them one by one?

Is there any function like `Shift + drag` for selecting several sprites?